# How to determine which SemanticModel instance resolves an ExpressionSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn

To find the target of an ExpressionSyntax instance I call `mySemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(myExpressionSyntax).`
I have several SemanticModel instances that each relate to a code file's syntax tree.

I want to iterate the semantic models and find the appropriate one to return the symbol information, but I can't see how to test for the appropriate semantic model without using exceptions.

I need the following code completing:

```
SymbolInfo? Resolve(ExpressionSyntax expressionSyntax)
{
    foreach (SemanticModel semanticModel in allSemanticModels)
    {
        if ( /* test if expression syntax found in semantic model */ )
        {
            return semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(expressionSyntax);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SemanticModels are bound to an underlying SyntaxTree, so you just need to make sure those lined up. If you had an `IEnumerable<SemanticModel>` you'd just have to do:

```
var model = models.First(m => m.SyntaxTree == expressionSyntax.SyntaxTree);
```

To pick out the right one; you're probably better off having a `Dictionary<SyntaxTree, SemanticModel>` rather than enumerating a list each time. I'm not sure exactly why you'd use any other data structure to hold them.

The only main advantage too of holding onto an SemanticModel is you get some caching benefits, trading memory in the process; don't be holding onto SemanticModels you're not going to use anymore.

Comment: Many thanks, Jason!  The dictionary tip makes perfect sense given that the syntax tree is available to key on -- cheers.